# How to pipe virtual files?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, cat, inkscape

I am using these commands to convert some files in inkscape:

```
python dxf_input.py sample.dxf > output_ink.svg
python scour.inkscape.py output_ink.svg > output.svg
```

This method works prefectly fine. However, I do not want to have to create the file "output_ink.svg". Instead, I'd like to pipe this file to the second command.

I have tried a bunch of things.

**using xargs:**

```
python dxf_input.py sample.dxf | xargs python scour.inkscape.py > output.svg
```

> scour.inkscape.py: error: no such option: -3

```
python dxf_input.py sample.dxf | xargs -I{} python scour.inkscape.py {} > output.svg
```

> xargs: argument line too long

**using FIFO:**

```
python scour.inkscape.py <(>(python dxf_input.py sample.dxf))
```

> xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

**using regular pipe:**

```
python dxf_input.py sample.dxf | python scour.inkscape.py > output.svg
```

> IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Do you know if `scour.inkscape.py` needs to seek within its file?

Comment: ...also, where in the world did you get the `<(>(...))` syntax from?

Comment: xargs would never work. `a | xargs b` - take the output from a, and convert it to command line arguments for program `b`. e.g. `echo 1 2 3|xargs grep somefile` would the equivalent of just having run `grep somefile 1`, `grep somefile2`, `grep somefile 3` in sequence.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't know that one.

Comment: It's the key question here, since it's impossible to seek inside a FIFO.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all programs *can* accept input from any kind of a FIFO -- be that a regular pipe, a named pipe, a `/dev/fd/NN` descriptor (as created by `<()` on platforms where this is permissible), etc -- because FIFOs are inherently non-seekable: You can't go back to the beginning and reread prior contents as you could with a regular file; you can't skip directly ahead to a different part of the file and come back later; etc.

Thus, there exists no solution which will work for all possible programs within the constraint of requiring a "pipe".

---

First, what will work *if* `scour.inkscape.py` can read from a FIFO:

```
python scour.inkscape.py <(python dxf_input.py sample.dxf)
```

If it can't read from a FIFO, but instead requires a regular file, bash doesn't have a relevant primitive, but zsh does:

```
# This needs zsh, not bash
python scour.inkscape.py =(python dxf_input.py sample.dxf)
```

Comment: I've already tried this. It say "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0"

Comment: Presumably it needs a real file, not a FIFO. Would need to dig into the source to see why, and since you don't link to the software...

Comment: @ChristophBühler, ...I've amended to show a zsh-only approach which will work even given that limitation.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thank you. I will just create the file!

Comment: ...or you could patch `scour.inkscape.py` appropriately, to be able to stream its inputs.

Comment: maybe this line? input = file(self.args[0], "r")

Comment: no, there's nothing wrong with that line. Have you linked to the source yet? We can't troubleshoot on nothing but speculation.

Comment: okay, I will just create a file.. I have already wasted 4 hours ^^